# Laravel remove decimal value when using laravel insert eloquent

Tags: php, laravel

I try to insert a decimal value into database, but Laravel removes that decimal value.

for example

```
$price = $request->price; //12.8
$array = [
  "product" => "xxx",
  "price" => $price
];

Models::insert($array);
```

but, in database record, it only showed `12` in `price` field.

for further information, price field datatype in my database is `decimal(10,2)`

if I added `(string) $price` or `DB::raw($price)` it worked fine.

Is there another way to insert decimal value to database without `DB::raw` or convert it into string??

Comment: Its always adviced to store monetary value in its lowest unit as a whole number e.g if you're saving 5.5 dollar, you save as cent i.e 550 cents because of decimal point's issues

Comment: are you using it like this $table->decimal('price', 12, 2); 12= total number of digits, 2 = number of decimal digits  ?

Comment: yes that's my current situation @ElenaRoman

Comment: thanks for your advice, but this is my current project, so I need to store it as a decimal when the value is end up with decimal. @OluwatobiSamuelOmisakin

Comment: Your datatype is `decimal(10.2)` or `decimal(10,2)`? Don't know if the first one is even possible when confirming a table creation, but if that's the case, these are probably different.

Comment: sorry it's decimal(10,2) @KévinBibollet

Comment: can you do a dd of price ?

Comment: I have updated the price value in question @ElenaRoman

Comment: Do you have a mutator in your model? e.g: `protected $casts = ['price' => 'integer']`?

Comment: i have already add `protected $casts = ['price' => 'decimal(16,2)']` but it was still not working, and i try yours change it to integer and it is still not working

Comment: I was not suggesting to change to integer... I was just asking. And I think the format is `['price' => 'decimal:2']` based on the doc https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting

Comment: still not working @cbaconnier

Comment: I cannot reproduce your behavior. `insert` works as it should and my DB preserve the decimals. `Models` is an Eloquent Model. Is this right?

Comment: @cbaconnier yes.. mine is only working when converting it to `(string) $price` or `DB::raw($price)`.?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: mysql @cbaconnier

Comment: The only things I can think of is; you have a library that broke something, changed the core of laravel, used a cast on `price`.. or on `$price`, somehow altered the `$price` before the `insert` or the value you did test was not  `12.8` . I don't see any other possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

If you have `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true,` set it to `false` and try again.

Comment: where is `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true,` location?

Comment: Database config usually.

Comment: Thank you! Just saved me a lot of issue, moving to Laravel 5.8 and PHP7.4 seemed to trigger this

Comment: You can set it [like this](https://gist.github.com/MatteoOreficeIT/4e4f117d1efbbebb43c86e80749cf61c): `\DB::getPdo()->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, true);`